# Flash / Flex Full Screen Scaling Remove Border

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I'm writing a standalone windows AIR app and using

```
contextView.stage.align  = StageAlign.TOP;
contextView.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
contextView.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

Which will scale my app to full screen and show the entire app with no cropping, however may leave borders on the left and right. Which it does

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove or at least set the color of those borders, they are currently white. Its a big wide 2" section on the left only in my case.

So I found out how to change the color of it, by doing a backgroundColor="#f3f3f3" on

See attached image below
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "remove" those borders? Either your application is Fullscrren and covers the whole screen, or it is not, and when scaled, shows backgroundcolor to cover the full screen.

Comment: I added an image to explain, the whole side is white by default, now I fixed that but the border remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the skin for the panel had a border. I changed it to only display in normal state and thus gone in other states. This was done by setting the state to include in, **includeIn="normal"**

```
<s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" includeIn="normal">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0" alpha="0.50" weight="1" />
    </s:stroke>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0xf3f3f3"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```